# gmaps4rails display location based on latitude and longitude

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I am using gmaps4rails with Rails 3.0.9. I would like to add a marker based on the latitude and longitude coordinates to the map, but I can't figure out how should I do it. I managed to use the map with an andress only. Thanks.

The code I'm using:

*app/models/location.rb*

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_gmappable :process_geocoding => false

  def gmaps4rails_address
    "#{self.latitude}, #{self.longitude}"
  end
end
```

app/controllers/locations_controller.rb

```
def index
@json = Location.first.to_gmaps4rails

respond_to do |format|
  format.html
end
```

*app/views/locations/index.html.erb*

```
<%= gmaps4rails(@json) %>
```

The `location` model contains the following fields: `latitude, longitude, address`.

UPDATE: I found the solution after reading one more time project's wiki about markers. The solution is to use custom `<%= gmaps %>` method. I managed to use it like this:

```
<%= gmaps({
    "map_options" => { "type" => "ROADMAP", "center_longitude" => 28.9, "center_latitude" => 47.03, "zoom" => 12, "auto_adjust" => true},
    "markers" => { "data" => @markers }
    })
    %>
```

In the controller:

```
@markers = '[
             {"description": "", "title": "", "sidebar": "", "lng": "28.8701", "lat": "47.0345", "picture": "", "width": "", "height": ""},
             {"lng": "28.9", "lat": "47" }
            ]'
```

You can customize these values as you like.

Comment: Can you post the code you are using now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try geocoder gem instead of gmaps4rails
https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder
http://www.rubygeocoder.com/

I think it is much better than gmaps4rails

Comment: @AlexanderGiraldo May be I'm wrong but I don't think you can plot the address on map using `Geocoder`